# How to change special symbols in string?

Tags: ruby, regex

For example I have a string

```
s = "start |foo bar|, middle, |reg ex| end"
```

and I would like to change `|` on square brackets, to get

```
"start [foo bar], middle, [reg ex] end"
```

How can I achieve it by using regex?
At least, I would like to capture `|foo bar|` and `|reg ex|`, but my method:

```
/\|.+\|/
```

captures `|foo bar|, middle, |reg ex|`

```
s.match(/\|.+\|/)[0] # => "|foo bar|, middle, |reg ex|"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making the regex non-greedy:

```
/\|.+?\|/
```

or

```
/\|[^|]+\|/
```

Answer (score 2):

```
"start |foo bar|, middle, |reg ex| end".gsub(/\|(.+?)\|/, '[\1]')
=> "start [foo bar], middle, [reg ex] end" 

"start |foo bar|, middle, |reg ex| end".gsub(/\|(.+?)\|/) do |str|
  puts $1
end

foo bar
reg ex
=> "start , middle,  end"
```